# Calling/Invoking a Javascript function from python a flask function within html

Tags: javascript, python, function, flask, routes

I was creating a flask application and tried to call a python function in which I wanted to invoke some javascript function/code regarding the HTML template that I returned on the initial `app.route('/')`

If the user did something, then I called another function that should invoke or call a js function I have tried looking everywhere but I cannot make any sense of the solutions.

Here is the structure of my code:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #verify if the file is valid
        #here invoke js to do something (for example flash("test"))
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <input type=file name=file>
      <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could execute a JavaScript function on load and have the function check for the condition. You can influence the outcome of this check by changing the condition with Python. If you use the [render_template](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/templates/) function of Flask, you do not have to write your HTML code within your Python file. For better readability I am using this functionality, but you can always put the HTML code into your Python code, as you have done before.

Your HTML template, e.g. named `upload.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Upload new File</title>
</head>
<body onload="flashMessage()">
  <script>
    function flashMessage() {
      if ("{{ flash_message }}" == "True") {
        alert("[YOUR_MESSAGE_HERE]");
      }
    }
  </script>

  <h1>Upload new File</h1>
  <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <input type=file name=file>
    <input type=submit value=Upload>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Your Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #verify if the file is valid
        #here invoke js to do something (for example flash("test"))
        return render_template('upload.html', flash_message="True")

    return render_template('upload.html', flash_message="False")
```

So, the condition line in your HTML file will render to

```
if ("True" == "True")
```

or

```
if ("False" == "True")
```

depending on if you want the flash message to show or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can just pass an argument, eg: "flash_message" to the render_template function

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    # YOUR CODE...

    return render_template('upload.html', flash_message=True)
```

Then you can check if the flash_message argument is True, if it meets the condition the js gets loaded, otherwise it does not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Upload new File</title>
</head>

<body>
    {% if flash_message %}
    <script>
        function YourFunction() {
            alert("[YOUR_MESSAGE_HERE]");
        }

        YourFunction();
    </script>
    {% endif %}

    <h1>Upload new File</h1>

    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
        <input type=file name=file>
        <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This successfully adds the script with the function after the page is rendered, but "YourFunction()" was never called.